# Flex item - fill the remaining container height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to have flex container with certain unknown height containing two items. The first items has fixed height 100px, second item should fill the rest of the container. How to achieve this? Here's my code (*note: I have set up fixed height to the container for testing purposes, as I said before, I don't know this height in CSS so I can't set height 400px to second item*):

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" style="height:100px">111 111 11</div>
  <div class="flex-item">x</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}

  .flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;

    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Thank you

PS: I want pure CSS solution, no JS

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it:

Added to second item this css:

```
 -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lqdiI